Isa 57:9 “You have journeyed to the king with oil And increased your perfumes;" pertains to warning Christians who become addicted to power
( Related posting:  (Proverbs 23:1-3) what does Not desiring deceptive food have anything to do with behaving while dining with important leaders?  )
( Related Posting:  https://www.worthychristianforums.com/topic/285674-it-takes-two-to-tango-when-it-comes-to-cultivating-the-relationship-between-leaders-especially-politicians-their-peoples-constituents-voters-and-that-would-be-themselves/#comment-3585767 )

Isaiah 57:5-10
New American Standard Bible 1995
Who inflame yourselves among the oaks,
[5] Under every luxuriant tree, Who slaughter the children in the ravines, Under the clefts of the rocks? [6] “Among the smooth stones of the ravine Is your portion, they are your lot; Even to them you have poured out a drink offering, You have made a grain offering. Should I relent of these things? [7] “On a high and lofty mountain You have made your bed. You also went up there to offer sacrifice. [8] “Behind the door and the doorpost You have set up your sign; Indeed, far removed from Me, you have uncovered yourself, And have gone up and made your bed wide. And you have made an agreement for yourself with them, You have loved their bed, You have looked at their manhood. [9] “You have journeyed to the king with oil And increased your perfumes; You have sent your messengers a great distance And made them go down to Sheol. [10] “You were tired out by the length of your road, Yet you did not say, ‘It is hopeless!’ You found renewed strength, Therefore you did not faint.

Is Isaiah 57:9 related to matter of degree regarding how Christians approach power?
When one reads the Isaiah 57:9 bible verse, would it be correct to interpret said verse in such a manner that it a warning or rebuke to Christians who become addicted to  political and/or leadership power or enamoured by the individuals who are in political and/or leadership power?
Please do Not misunderstand me, it’s alright for Christians to be in positions of power or be advisors to people who are in power.
Daniel, Shadrach, Meshach and Abed-nego were all high-level ranking bureaucrats and civil servants who served foreign kings, and that’s alright.
However, even though Shadrach, Meshach and Abed-nego were blessed with political power as civil servants, they knew when to say "No" regarding crossing a line which is evidenced in Daniel 3:16-18.  Essentially, Shadrach, Meshach and Abed-nego rejected King Nebuchadnezzar's order to worship an idol statute.

Daniel 3:16-18
New American Standard Bible 1995
[16] Shadrach, Meshach and Abed-nego replied to the king, “O
Nebuchadnezzar, we do not need to give you an answer concerning this
matter. [17] If it be so, our God whom we serve is able to deliver us
from the furnace of blazing fire; and He will deliver us out of
your hand, O king. [18] But even if He does not, let it be known to you, O king, that we are not going to serve your gods or worship the golden image that you have set up.”

Isaiah 57:9 seems to be a warning to Christians who get so emotionally enamored with those in power to the point where they might forfeit their Christian lifestyle.
Using the "scripture interprets scripture" tool, one should keep in mind the following verse comes to mind:

2 Corinthians 6:14
New American Standard Bible 1995
Do not be bound together with unbelievers; for what partnership
have righteousness and lawlessness, or what fellowship has light with
darkness?
2 Corinthians 6:14
English Standard Version ('The Temple of the Living God')
Do not be unequally yoked with unbelievers. For what partnership
has righteousness with lawlessness? Or what fellowship has light with
darkness?

Is Isaiah 57:9 related to matter of degree regarding how Christians approach power?
When one reads the Isaiah 57:9 bible verse, would it be correct to interpret said verse in such a manner that it a warning or rebuke to Christians who become addicted to  political and/or leadership power or enamoured by the individuals who are in political and/or leadership power?

The context of Isaiah 57:9 shows people who go to great lengths to gain the favor of primarily idols, but do not put any thought or effort into a relationship with God (YHWH,"I Am").  I think a better passage to address the point you are trying to make is Isaiah 31:1.  Ultimately, men are looking to other 'gods' for a savior, probably to avoid the uncomfortable truth of  the consequences of their own sin.
